# Android Studio / How to apply SharedPreferenced to my code

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I'm doing Quiz in Android Studio. The game is divided into two categories. After passing the first category, the second button (opening the second category) changes the status from setEnable "false" to "true". **How to use the SharedPreferenced method in my code that the changes related to the second button (.setEnable) will be saved after closing the application.**

Last level of first category

```
public class win extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
Button win1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_winflagi);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    win1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.winflagi);
    win1.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v==win1)
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(win.this, Activity2.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("isEnabled", "enabled");
        startActivity(myIntent);

    }

}
}
```

- Class containing a buttons for two categories ...
- button3 opened the first category
- entrycity opens the second category

  ```
  public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
  Button button3;
  Button entrycity;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

  setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

  button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
  button3.setOnClickListener(this);

  entrycity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.entrycity);
  entrycity.setOnClickListener(this);

  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(final View v) {
  final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.menu);
  if (v == button3) {

      startActivity(new Intent(Activity2.this, flagi1.class));
      Bungee.zoom(this);
      mp.start();

  }

  if (v== entrycity){

      Intent intent=getIntent();
      String isEnabled = intent.getStringExtra("isEnabled");
      if(isEnabled==null||isEnabled.equals("disabled")){
          entrycity.setEnabled(false);
      }
      else{
          entrycity.setEnabled(true);
          startActivity(new Intent(this, cities1.class));
      }
      }

  }

  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Set a boolean preference when you are enabling the Button.

```
else{
     entrycity.setEnabled(true);
     getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("isEnabled",true).apply();
     startActivity(new Intent(this, cities1.class));
    }
```

and in your onCreate set the enabled status of the button based on the preference :

```
entrycity.setEnabled(getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("isEnabled",false));
```

Comment: I tried it and when i'm exit from app, changes not saving :\

Comment: oops.. Made a typo. The name of the sharedPreference is MY_PREF, not userdetails

Comment: If you expect it to be written in the next Activity, then use `commit()` instead of `apply()`. And suppress the lint warning.

Comment: Do not compare view with "==" use equals() or compare views id (v.getId() == btn.getId())